# I tried to hide an element but it return this error

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this code in my html file `<button onclick="startGame" class="startBtn">Start</button>`

And this in my JavaScript

```
var start = document.querySelector(".starter");

var game = document.querySelector(".game");

var submit = document.querySelector(".submit");

function startGame() {

  start.classList.add("hide");

  game.classList.remove("hide");

}
```

But when I run this it shows the error like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksnIV.jpg)

I tried to hide an element and show another with this function.
But return the error

Comment: What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Use the correct selector? We can’t see your HTML and have no way of knowing if it’s right or being used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

looks like start variabel didn't find your element. try console.log(start) to check does it get the html element or not